# Can we do table partition in SQL Server 2012 Standard Edition

Tags: view, sql-server-2012, database-administration, database-partitioning

I have one table which are number of rows '7515966' and this table depend on another tables. We create View for generating SSRS reports.
Now size of View is increase so that performance issue occur on report.
We start archiving data for large table. but i can't understand which methodology use please guide us..
Thank you...

Answer (score 1):

Table partitioning in 2012 is only available in Enterprise Edition. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=sql.110).aspx for details on what's available for each edition.

7million rows is not a lot of rows for SQL Server, we routinely deal with billions of rows. However, as your rows get into the 10s of millions range, you'll probably expose various performance gaps in your system. E.g. are your queries efficiently written so they only touch the rows they need, do you have the right indexes, are statistics up to date, is tempdb optimized, etc...

One common weak link in 9 out of 10 databases (regardless of make) I've worked with is the storage subsystem. Is yours able to keep up with the large data set you need to work with. Storage for databases should be designed and configured based on throughput, concurrency and latency requirements first. Space generally the last thing to worry about once the other requirements, including HA/DR, are met.

If you have deficiencies in your current system, you can pay for the expensive enterprise edition and implement table partitioning but you will likely still suffer performance problems soon after, if not immediately.

Comment: Thanks for Reply SQLmojoe,